# How to re-create encrypted and/or signed email message using EWS API?

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I`ve got the whole body ([GetItemOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getitem-operation-email-message)) of the encrypted email message (PKI approach). Now I want to re-create this email using the request to [CreateItemOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/createitem-operation-email-message). The problem is that the email appears without encrypted and/or signed flag inside the user mailbox and the message content re-created as attachment **smime.p7m**.
My questions is How to properly re-create encrypted and/or signed email message using EWS API. (Please, do not advise me to use any .NET code).